# How can I capture video of my iPad, while making touches visible?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak

I want to capture some video of my iPad.

Doing this via VNC on a PC seems like a good choice.

However is there a possibility to make my touches visible?

Comment: If your iPad has been jailbreaked then the "DisplayOut" app shows touches.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to it. Display Recorder from the same author is the answer to all of my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Recorder from the same author does exactly that.

Thanks to Vaccano.